# How to use Symfony EasyAdmin with entities having a constructor?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Does EasyAdmin support entity classes with constructor arguments for properties that are meant to be not nullable? EasyAdmin instantiates the entity class even if you click the "Add " button, right? Unfortunatelly this results in an "Too few arguments to function __construct()" error. Do you have a solution for this problem?

I tend to use the constructor for entity properties that are not nullable. Unfortunatelly EasyAdmin throws errors like this one when I click on the e.g. `Add FiscalYear` button to create a new entity object (`FiscalYear` in my example):

```
Too few arguments to function App\Entity\FiscalYear::__construct(), 0 passed in /myProject/vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Controller/AdminControllerTrait.php on line 618 and exactly 2 expected
```

How can I prevent these errors? As you can see in the following entity class the two constructor arguments represent the data that is meant to be submitted via the form:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FiscalYearRepository")
 */
class FiscalYear
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": 0})
     */
    private bool $completed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="fiscalYears")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Company $company;

    public function __construct(int $title, Company $company)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): int
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(int $title): void
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getCompleted(): bool
    {
        return $this->completed;
    }

    public function setCompleted(bool $completed): void
    {
        $this->completed = $completed;
    }

    public function getCompany(): Company
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function setCompany(Company $company): void
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to let EasyAdmin show the "create a new entity object" form without instantiating the entity class?

Comment: This does not seem to be a useful option: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#override-the-admincontroller-methods-per-entity

Answer (score 3):

No, EasyAdmin doesn't natively support constructor with argument.

To avoid this problem, you have three solution.

**solution1: Override EasyAdminController**

[The documentation explains this method.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#override-the-admincontroller-methods-per-entity)

```php
// src/Controller/AdminController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController;

class FiscalYearController extends EasyAdminController
{
    public function createNewFiscalYearEntity()
    {
        //your own logic here to retrieve title and company
        return new FiscalYear($title, $company);
    }
}
```

Depending you business model, it could be very difficult to retrieve title and company

**solution2: Respect the entity pattern and help your business model with a factory pattern**

1. Your entities should respect the entity pattern and their constructor should be edited to remove arguments.
2. To replace your constructor in your business model, create a factory.

```php
class FiscalYearFactory 
{
   public static function create(int $title, Company $company): FiscalYear
   {
       $fiscalYear = new FiscalYear();
       $fiscalYear->setCompany($company);
       $fiscalYear->setTitle($title);

       return $fiscalYear;
   }
}
```

in your model, you have to do some updates:

```php
//Comment code like this in your business model
$fiscalYear = new FiscalYear(2020,$company);
//Replace it, by this code:
$fiscalYear = FiscalYearFactory::create(2020,$company);
```

**Solution3 Accept null values in your constructor.**

I do NOT like this solution. Your properties shall be edited too to accept null values, your getters shall be edited to return null value. This is a solution, but I discourage you to use it.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FiscalYearRepository")
 */
class FiscalYear
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": 0})
     */
    private bool $completed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="fiscalYears")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Company $company;

    public function __construct(?int $title = null, ?Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?int
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
```

You should use the first solution which is a better practice

Comment: Thx. Unfortunatelly solution 1 is not an option because the two constructor arguments `$title` and `$company` is (part of) the data that is meant to be set in the form by an editor. Solution 2 may work but I am not sure if I like to replace the constructor with a static `create()` method. I agree that solution 3 is to be avoided.

Comment: I understand what you said about solution2. After years of development (and bugs :) ), I'm now convinced that this is not a good practice to add arguments in constructor. When I added arguments in your constructors, you was mixing my business model with my entities and I avoid it now, because entities are only here to be stored. No logic inside, only getters and setters. Or you could encountered bugs like this one with EasyAdmin.